# Error NU1107 Version conflict detected for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Install/reference while installing EF core

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I installed a visual studio 2017 and I have created a MVC project called WebApplication1.

In the Dependencies-> NuGet I have the files

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.App(2.2.0)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design(2.2.0).

In Dependencies->SDK:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.App(2.2.0)
- Microsoft.NETCore.App (2.2.0)

I want to install Entity Framework Core for my project.

Thus I right click on my project and select "Manage Nuget Packages" and then in brows section I enter "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" in the serch bar and choose it then install. However the console shows me two errors for installing:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for
>   'WebApplication1'.                 Error  NU1107  Version conflict detected for
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Install/reference
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.1 directly to project
>   WebApplication1 to resolve this issue.   WebApplication1 ->
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.1 ->
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 3.1.1 ->
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 3.1.1)   WebApplication1 ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>=
>   2.2.0 && < 2.3.0).    WebApplication1 F:\Div\workspace\CSDDashboard.net project\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.csproj   1

I have searched a lot on the internet to find any solution but till now I'm not successful. I appreciate if anyone could solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You have to select 2.2.0 version when installing the **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer** package

In Manage Nuget Packages window

[image]

Or use Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 2.2.0
```

or add this line to your csproj file

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.0" />
```